# How to pass a Javascript array to the Spring Controller Class

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I created the JS array and try to pass the array to the Controller class, but there it is showing the `NullPointerException`.

I checked the URL through FireBug there the values are passing but in controller class if I try to retrive it is showing NULL.

JavaScript Code:

```
var deleteWidgetId = new Array(); //array created 
deleteWidgetId[0] = "a";//adding values 
deleteWidgetId[1] = "b"; 
//action trigged 
$("#saveLayout").load("layout/saveLayout.action", 
 { deleteWidgetId : deleteWidgetId },      
 function(response, status, xhr) { });
```

Java Code (In controller class):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveLayout")
public ModelAndView saveLayout(@RequestParam String[] deleteWidgetId) throws Exception { 
    //here that if i try to use the deleteWidgetId it is giving null pointer exception
}
```

Comment: **JavaScript Code:**
    
       *var deleteWidgetId = new Array(); //array created
        deleteWidgetId[0] = "a";//adding values
        deleteWidgetId[0] = "b";
    
    //action trigged
        $("#saveLayout").load("layout/saveLayout.action", {
          deleteWidgetId : deleteWidgetId
         }, function(response, status, xhr) {
        });*

Comment: **Java Code:(In controller class)**
            
        *@RequestMapping(value = "/saveLayout")
            public ModelAndView saveLayout(@RequestParam String[] deleteWidgetId) throws Exception {
        //here that if i try to use the deleteWidgetId it is giving null pointer exception
        }*

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `List<String>` instead of `String[]`

Comment: I try this using the List<string> but still it is showing the Null for that deleteWidgetId

Comment: Try to rename deleteWidgetId js variable to deleteWidgetIdValues

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the name of the request parameter within the annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveLayout")
public ModelAndView saveLayout(@RequestParam(value="deleteWidgetId") String[] deleteWidgetId) throws Exception { 
    //here that if i try to use the deleteWidgetId it is giving null pointer exception
}
```