# how to pass list from javascript to spring controller

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have issue of how can javaScript can pass two sepparate lists to spring controller. On my freeMarker template I made option to change set of two lists. 
This is render of two lists:

EDITED: I found that Jquery have Ui plagin with

```
.sortable("toArray", { key: "id" })
```

method, so I added Id value to < li> tag

```
<div class="span5" id="listBox">
            <h3>Assigned Servers</h3>
            <#if assignedServers?has_content>
                <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                    <#list assignedServers as responsible >
                        <li class="ui-state-default"
                            id="${responsible.id}" >${responsible.server_name}</li>
                    </#list>
                </ul>
            <#else>
                <h4>This employee have no assigned servers yet.</h4>
            </#if>
        </div>

        <div class="span5" id="listBox">
            <h3>Available Servers</h3>
            <#if availableServers?has_content>
                <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                    <#list availableServers as available >
                        <li class="ui-state-default"
                            id="${available.id}" >${available.server_name}</li>
                    </#list>
                </ul>
            <#else>
                <h4>There is no available servers to assign.</h4>
            </#if>
        </div>
```

EDITED: I changed JQuery function:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var assigned = "";
            var available = "";

            $('#sortable1').sortable({
                connectWith: '#sortable2',
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    assigned = $(this).sortable("toArray", { key: "id" });
                    }
            }).disableSelection();

            $('#sortable2').sortable({
                connectWith: '#sortable1',
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    available = $(this).sortable("toArray", { key: "id" });
                    }
            }).disableSelection();

            $('#assign').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ServerMonitoring/employee_management/serv_assignment/2",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                         serversListModel: {
                             "assignedServers": assigned,
                             "availableServers": available
                         }
                     }),
                    datatype: "jsondata",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("Error: " + e);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
            //debugger
        });
    </script>
```

EDITED: this is my new spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView onSubmit(
        @ModelAttribute("serversListModel") ServersListModel serversListModel,
        @PathVariable("id") Long responsibleId,
        BindingResult result,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        SessionStatus status) throws ParseException {

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        if (serversListModel.getAvailableServers() != null) {
            for (String id : serversListModel.getAvailableServers()) {
                ServerEntity entity = employeeService.getServerById((long)Integer.parseInt(id));
                entity.setResponsible(responsibleId);
                adminService.updateServer(entity);
            }
        }

        if (serversListModel.getAssignedServers() != null) {
            for (String id : serversListModel.getAssignedServers()) {
                ServerEntity entity = employeeService.getServerById((long)Integer.parseInt(id));
                entity.setResponsible((long) 0);
                adminService.updateServer(entity);
            }
        }
        status.setComplete();
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employee_management/employee_manager");


    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employee_management/serv_assignment");
    }

}
```

EDITED: new ServersListModel - it's a simple POJO with two vars

```
public class ServersListModel {

private List<String> assignedServers;

private List<String> availableServers;
...
}
```

By debuging in FireBug ican se that JSON is passing String:

```
{"serversListModel":{"assignedServers":["2","4"],"availableServers":["1","5","3","6","7","8"]}}
```

But, I still didn't manage to resive that string, vars in my model stil contain NULL on debuging. 
Placing @RequestBody anotation on place of @ModelAttribute("serversListModel") makes Jquery throw BadRequest error.
If, inside the method body, I call

```
String jsonBody = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
```

it will return JSON String object with requerd id, so i'm reaky near to answer.

Please help me to find out the mistake in Controller. Thank you.

Comment: What does your controller method look like?

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187123/how-to-pass-a-javascript-array-to-the-spring-controller-class

Comment: @superEb, I added the controller code.

Comment: What does the body of the POST request look like? (Capture the request with an HTTP proxy, like Chrome Dev Tools, Fiddler2, or Charles) I'm not sure how jQuery converts your JSON object into *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* but I'm guessing there's a mismatch between what jQuery is sending and what your controller expects.

Comment: @superEb,all that i find in the POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded is: update=Assign - it comes from buttons of form.

Comment: So you may have to do your own form binding/conversion in JavaScript and set `processData` to false, or just POST JSON and possibly use `@RequestBody` in your controller instead of `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: @superEb, please check my changes. Maybe you could find a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue and i like to share the solution with you:

I changed my model to Long type:

```
public class ServersListModel {

private List<Long> assignedServers;

private List<Long> availableServers;
```

Then I added Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

and configured Jackson like this:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultViews"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
```

(I was not cecking if all of them are important =))

Naw my JQury.Ajax script look like this:

```
 $(function() {
            var assigned = "";
            var available = "";

            $('#sortable1').sortable({
                connectWith: '#sortable2',
                dropOnEmpty: true,
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    assigned = $(this).sortable("toArray", { key: "id" });
                    }
            }).disableSelection();

            $('#sortable2').sortable({
                connectWith: '#sortable1',
                dropOnEmpty: true,
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    available = $(this).sortable("toArray", { key: "id" });
                    }
            }).disableSelection();

            $('#assign').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ServerMonitoring/employee_management/serv_assignment/2",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                            assignedServers: assigned,
                            availableServers: available
                    }),
                    datatype: "json",
                    'scriptCharset': "utf-8",
                    'contentType': "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        //alert("Error: " + e);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
            //debugger
        });
```

And finaly my MVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody  ModelAndView onSubmit(
        @RequestBody ServersListModel serversListModel,
        @PathVariable("id") Long responsibleId,
        BindingResult result,
        SessionStatus status) throws ParseException, IOException {

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        if (serversListModel.getAssignedServers() != null) {
            for (Long id : serversListModel.getAssignedServers()) {
                ServerEntity entity = employeeService.getServerById(id);
                entity.setResponsible(responsibleId);
                adminService.updateServer(entity);
            }
        }

        if (serversListModel.getAvailableServers() != null) {
            for (Long id : serversListModel.getAvailableServers()) {
                ServerEntity entity2 = employeeService.getServerById(id);
                entity2.setResponsible((long) 0);
                adminService.updateServer(entity2);
            }
        }
        status.setComplete();
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employee_management/employee_manager");
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employee_management/serv_assignment");
    }
}
```

Everything work just perfect. Enjoy !!!